# Batch Class Processing Failed

Tags: apex, batch

We have a batch class which process large number of records and each record will go through lot of updation and validation in the execute method.
So we have executed the batch class with reducing the number of records processed per batch using the syntax like

```
BatchClass batchClsObj =  new BatchClass();
Database.executeBatch(batchClsObj,1);
```

This process only one record per batch. Even though we have reduced the number of records processed per batch at a very minimal level. We are still facing the issue. Please look at the last two batch records [image: Batch error information]

My query in start method:

```
 String selStmt = 'Select Id' + ' from Account' + ' where Id in (Select Parent_Account_vod__c ' 
     + ' from Child_Account_vod__c where Copy_Address_vod__c = true) ' + ' and Id in 
     (Select Account_vod__c from address_vod__c where SystemModstamp >= ' + lastSync.formatGMT
     ('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'') +') ';
```

Comment: I have seen that before. It happens in the SF query locator code (line number in my case did not exist in my code) and they way we worked around it was do break out the queries with NO subqueries and reducing the filter data to almost nothing. The we processed the records in the execute to determine if it needed to be processed further. Basically reduce your query in the start method to the most minimal need to query the object. It was the only way as SF support was no help despite providing a ton of documentation....Hope this is not your issue but it is worth a shot. Maybe share the query?

Comment: Restructuring the query done in the `start` to be on an object where the amount of work done in the `execute` is bounded is a good way to go if your problem can be structured that way. For example, rather than querying a parent object that has an indeterminate number of child objects in the `start`, query the child object in the `start`. But whether that sort of change can be done depends on the specifics of the work you are trying to do.

Comment: Here goes my query in start method 

String selStmt = 'Select Id' +
                      ' from Account' + 
                      ' where Id in (Select Parent_Account_vod__c ' + 
                      ' from Child_Account_vod__c where Copy_Address_vod__c = true) ' + 
                      ' and Id in (Select Account_vod__c  from address_vod__c where SystemModstamp >= ' +
                      lastSync.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'') +') ';